# Is it possible from web interface to export Notes' dates?

Tags: export, dates

We are attempting to download all details on some of our donors, including the notes, but do not see among the fields to be exported the date of Notes. We can export the Note itself, but no details about it despite being able to see it on the individual contacts' profiles. We also do not have access to the backend and cannot create MySQL or other scripts to get to it. Are we SOL?

Answer (score 2):

Just had a quick play on the demo site and notes and note date fields become searchable/ accessible using the Data Processor extension.

Add note as data source, and contact as additional data source if you want to export note and related contact record at same time (linking Note Entity ID and Contact ID)

And then add a csv export as a data output

Comment: Thanks, Craig. Unfortunately, I think that is also beyond our internal capacities. We're not able to add any extensions to our CiviCRM. I presume we'll have to contract with an external developer to add that or otherwise just do a data dump and pull the note dates from that.